# Cross Validated Newsletter Feb 18 2021

Tags: discussion

Is it just me, or did anyone else not receive Newsletter for the Feb 18 ? Is there some way to get it ?

Also I noticed in the last few newsletters that the "hits from previous week" section was not there. Is this a permanent thing ?

Comment: Did you mean to post this on the main meta site? It seems to be about the whole network rather than just CV.

Comment: What is the "Cross Validated Newsletter"??

Comment: @whuber thats an email that comes once a week with the most popular questions that I subscribe under "Email Settings" under my profile: https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/email/digests/6884

Comment: I didn't know about this either. I guess it's there for anyone who wants it and does no harm. Any comments or evidence on who finds it useful?

Answer (score 3):

It's called the "Cross Validated Community digest."  Google gives a link to https://stats.stackexchange.com/digest/preview.

Comment: Thanks. The page on the site is called the community digest, but the actual email that I receive is called the "Newsletter" (that's the subject of the email that I received, not "digest"). Anyway, I'm looking for that from the Feb 18th one

Comment: That Web page doesn't even have a date.  Because the links go to recent questions, I suppose it presents only the most recent digest.  It looks like a living document that is constantly updated.